# ng-repeat по два элемента

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

У меня есть массив из 6-ти элементов (это пример элементов может быть сколько угодно), по которым я хочу сделать ng-repeat. Но я хочу, чтобы в блок ложилось по два элемента. На выходе должна получиться такая

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">1 элемент массива</div>
    <div class="col">2 элемент массива</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">3 элемент массива</div>
    <div class="col">4 элемент массива</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">5 элемент массива</div>
    <div class="col">6 элемент массива</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[используйте range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges)

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
     input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };
});
```

html:

```
            <tr data-ng-repeat="key in [] | range: items.length/2">
                <td>{{items[key]}}</td>
                <td>{{items[key+1]}}</td>
            </tr>
```

и будет Вам счастье!

Answer (score 0):

Только написать свою директиву.

Или свой фильтр и вложить второй `ng-repeat` внутрь первого.

Comment: Нет, нужно именно по два col в один row. 
Ну да, либо с дерективой заморочиться

Comment: @drm, тогда нужно свою директиву. Или свой фильтр и два вложенных ng-repeat.